# SQL Server Subquery Returning No Records

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have what should be a very simple subquery:

```
DECLARE @count TABLE (count1 INT, count2 INT)

SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bird) AS count1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fish) AS count2
FROM @count
```

- When I run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bird` I get 10 back.
- When I run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fish` I get 5 returned.
- When I run the above query, I get zero records returned.

Am I missing something? I've seen multiple different tutorials and they all say to do pretty much exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Why do you need the`FROM@count` and variable??  Can't you just do `Select (Select count(*) from bird) as count1, (select count(*) from fish) as Count2`?  What I suspect is happening is table @count has 0 records so no records are returned; regardless of counts in fish and bird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that you are trying to insert the two counts into your declared table. If this is true you are missing an `INSERT INTO` and there is one `FROM @count` you don't need...

In this example I use two count (on other tables) to insert one row into `@count`, which you can select in the last step:

```
declare @count table (count1 int, count2 int);

INSERT INTO @count
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.all_columns)
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables);

SELECT * FROM @count;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Why did none of the tutorials mention the insert into?

Comment: So, while we use MSSQL, once I switch over to Java it uses Oracle SQL, yes? Because in JAVA the query doesn't work, It is saying that I am getting no records returned.

Comment: @MarcelMarino, Please avoid chameleon questions... Just start a new question, tag it with `oracle (+ version)` and there will be lot of help soon. Oracle is not my dialect, sorry...

Comment: Okay, I didn't want to risk getting smacked with a duplicate question penalty.

Comment: @MarcelMarino There's no penalty... If the question is *bad* (poor input, no research effort), you risk a down-vote...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting records from @count table which does not have any records, you will always get the no records. Btw, what are you trying to achieve?