# Oracle Subquery Returning No Records

Tags: java, sql, oracle

We primarily use SQL Server for our queries, but it seems that when we use Java it runs in an Oracle engine. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603591/sql-server-subquery-returning-no-records/39603727) I asked for the SQL Server method of counting records from multiple tables since most of the time SQL Server runs the same as Oracle. I was able to get data returned from this query:

```
declare @count table (count1 int, count2 int, count3 int)
INSERT INTO @count
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bike),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Car),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Truck)
select * from @count;
```

However when putting this in Java I get an error that no records were returned. Any idea what I can do here to fix this up?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have table variables, so I'm befuddled by what code you might have actually run.

Comment: Regardless of the code I ran, what I need to know is how to get the counts for three separate tables in one query.

Comment: I prefer to separate my java and my sql by putting queries into stored procedures. If you are able to get your sql to work directly on the database then I think running inside a stored proc would be a strategy worth exploring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you need to use the `dual` table:

```
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bike),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Car),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Truck)
from dual;
```

If you need to return these values in a single row, then the following should work in either database:

```
select b.bcnt, c.ccnt, t.tcnt
from (SELECT COUNT(*) as bcnt FROM Bike) b cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as ccnt FROM Car) c cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as tcnt FROM Truck) t;
```

Comment: That second query did it for me. Thank you so much!